# quotes problems between freemarker, java and javascript

Tags: javascript, java, freemarker

i have a problem with single quotes, sending a word (for ex: patte't) from java to html (freemarker) then use the variable on a "onClick" js function

I have already tried to have an extra escape in java but the variable display will contains '\'(patte\'t). The onClick works fine in this case.
If i use a simple escape in java, the variable display is fine but the onClick deosn't work (parameter like: onClick('patte't')), i got an error in this case.

```
<tr id="contactList" onclick="Ws('${contact.id!''}','${contact.name!''}');">
some <td>
</tr>
contact.name contains a single quote in his value



ex:
Java send: pette't
html displays: pette't
onClick: error(onClick('patte't'))

Thanks everyone
```

Comment: What does `Ws` do? You might have to add a `?replace("'", "\\'")` there.

Comment: it works just fine with the replace, thanks a looot :)

Comment: Great that it works for you. I looked more into the freemarker documentation. And found that maybe `?js_string` is even better, try it.

Answer (score 1):

Two layer of escaping is needed in such case: JavaScript string escaping, and then HTML escaping.

For JavaScript string escaping, use `?js_string`. With that, you get something like `onclick="Ws('someId', 'patte\'t')"`. That still will be broken if the name contains `"`, as that will close the HTML attribute value, despite that `?js_string` will escape it as `\"` (as `\` has no special meaning in HTML). So the second layer is HTML escaping, which will replace `"` with `&quot;` and so on. The good practice is to turn on HTML auto-escaping when generating HTML pages; if it's not turned on on application level, turn it on. (If you can't then start the template with `<#ftl output_format='HTML'>`.)